# there exists $c \in (a,b)$

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ and $g$ be functions such that $f''$ and $g''$ exist. Let, for some $a<b$, $f(a)=f(b)=g(a)=g(b)=0$, and $g''(x) \neq 0$ for every $x \in (a,b)$. Show that there exists $c \in (a,b)$ such that

$$\frac{f(c)}{g(c)}=\frac{f''(c)}{g''(c)}$$

Comment: Please give it a look! http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$h(t)=f(t)g'(t)-g(t)f'(t),$$
and apply Rolle's theorem.

(This assumes $g\ne0$ on $(a,b)$ as well.)